# typescript react: polymorphic refs for any HTMLElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

is there a way to create polymorphic refs in functional components?

currently:

```
const r = createRef<Element>();
<div ref={r}></div>
```

fails with the dubious error that `RefObject<Element> is not assignable to LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>`

this makes polymorphic refs impossible. Ideally there is a way to use createRef to accept any `Element` or `HTMLElement`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Curious if you ever found a resolution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const r = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
```

Then it should work.

Comment: `HTMLDivElement` narrows the type to divs. I'm looking for a way to use the ref for all `Elements`.